# Unwanted Padding-Bottom on Image Overlay?

Tags: html, css, layout, padding

I added a padding bottom to an image class and wanted a hover overlay over the image, but it extends past the image including the added padding. Is there a way to make sure the hover spans just the image width and height without padding? Thanks!

```css
.work-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.work-image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.work-image:after, .work-image:before {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.work-image:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  content: '\A';
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.work-image:before {
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  content: attr(data-content);
}

.work-image:hover:after, .work-image:hover:before {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div data-content="Here is a caption" class="work-image">
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2l8w0hc.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div data-content="Here is a caption" class="work-image">
  <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2zodetx.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `vertical-align: bottom;` from `.work-image` to `.work-image img`, and replace `padding-bottom` with `margin-bottom`.

```css
.work-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;      
}
.work-image img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.work-image:after, .work-image:before {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.work-image:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  content: '\A';
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.work-image:before {
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  content: attr(data-content);
}

.work-image:hover:after, .work-image:hover:before {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div data-content="Here is a caption" class="work-image">
  <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2l8w0hc.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div data-content="Here is a caption" class="work-image">
  <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2zodetx.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```